# Create a mongoDB Database User from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to create a new User from my mongo Database from Nodejs. I know you can create a user via the cli like that:

```
db.createUser({
  user: 'USERNAME',
  pwd: passwordPrompt(),
  roles: [{
    role: 'readWrite',
    db: 'DATABASE'
  }]
})
```

But that is not what i am looking for, is there any way to create a User for the Database from within nodejs? Is there any libary to do such a thing or is there an api to create a new User?

Comment: Do you have any Node.js code at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDb node driver, the `createUser` is not available, instead you will have to use `addUser`

```
db.addUser('username', 'password' , {
 roles
})
```

You can refer to this api documentation provided by the official MongoDb node driver.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Db.html#addUser
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/interfaces/AddUserOptions.html

Comment: Sure, let me know if this works or not.